# Powershell "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm getting this below error trying to run this code and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Anyone ideas?

```
$ChocoPackage = "packagename"
$localprograms = choco list --localonly
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe" -ArgumentList "install $ChocoPackage -ia "'/D=C:\Program Files\packagename'" -y"
```

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/D=C:\Program Files\packagename'.
At C:\Program Files\install.ps1:3 char:5
+     Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.ex ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- As you point out in your own answer, [special quoting requirements](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/#how-to-pass-options-switches) apply to `choco.exe`'s `/ia` parameter.
- However, **since you are using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), it is *not* the instructions from the linked page for *PowerShell* that apply in this case, but the ones for `cmd.exe`** (even though there is *no* shell involved in this invocation; however, like `cmd.exe`, console applications themselves generally only understand `"..."` quoting); that is, your `-ArgumentList` string must end up containing the following *verbatim*, which is what the string passed to `-ArgumentList` below achieves via embedded `"` characters escaped as `` `" `` (`""` would work too):
  `"/D=""C:\Program Files\packagename"""`

```sh
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe" `
  -ArgumentList "install $ChocoPackage -ia `"/D=`"`"C:\Program Files\packagename`"`"`" -y"
```

Only if you call `choco.exe` *directly* from PowerShell do the PowerShell instructions apply (`'/D=""C:\Program Files\packagename""'`):

```sh
& "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe" install $ChocoPackage -ia '/D=""C:\Program Files\packagename""' -y
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

What you passed to `-ArgumentList` was composed of *three* directly adjoining string literals in the form `" a "' b '" c "`, to use a simplified example (i.e., a double-quoted string right next to single-quoted string, right next to another double-quoted string).

However, **PowerShell doesn't fully support *implicit* concatenation of directly adjoining string literals to form a single argument** the way that POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` do; doing so results in the strings being passed as *separate* arguments, which caused your problem (`Start-Process` saw extra positional parameters after `-ArgumentList` it didn't expect).

To demonstrate the original problem with the simplified example:

```sh
PS> Write-Output " a "' b '" c "
 a 
 b 
 c
```

That is, `Write-Output` received string literals `" a "`, `' b '`, and `" c "` as 3 separate arguments (as implied by their appearing on their own line each).

**Only if the *first* token is *unquoted* do you get a *single* string argument** composed of it and subsequent *quoted* tokens:

```sh
# *Single* argument, because `a` is *unquoted*.
PS> Write-Output a' b '" c "
a b  c
```

The same applies even if that first unquoted token is a (non-expression) *variable reference* (e.g., `Write-Output $HOME/'folder 1'/"and more"`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161666/45375) for more information

---

**If you do need to reliably form a single string argument from a mix of double-quoted (interpolating) and single-quoted (verbatim) string literals**, use **`(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), and the **`+`** operator for ***explicit* string concatenation**:

```sh
PS> Write-Output (" a " + ' b ' + " c ")
 a  b  c
```

Comment: With your skills for explaining things, you need to write a book - my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Oh course I figured it out almost immediately after reading the official Chocolatey documentation. Since I'm using powershell you have to be very specific in how you wrap spaces in quotes.

```
-ia '/yo=""Spaces spaces""'
```

https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/#how-to-pass-options-switches

> Pass quotes in arguments: When you need to pass quoted values to to something like a native installer, you are in for a world of fun. In cmd.exe you must pass it like this: -ia "/yo=""Spaces spaces""". In PowerShell.exe, you must pass it like this: -ia '/yo=""Spaces spaces""'. No other combination will work. In PowerShell.exe if you are on version v3+, you can try --% before -ia to just pass the args through as is, which means it should not require any special workarounds.

Comment: Good find on the special quoting requirements, but note that it is _not_ the PowerShell instructions that apply in your case, but the ones for `cmd.exe` (in the sense that you must use only `"..."` quoting), due to use of `Start-Process`; please see my answer for details.