# Using Powershell environmental variables as strings when outputting files

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, environment-variables, export-to-csv

I am using [Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo/3.5) to generate a computer's serial number and a hash code and export that info as a CSV.

Here is the code I usually use:

```
new-item "c:\Autopilot_Export" -type directory -force

Set-Location "C:\Autopilot_Export"

Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile Autopilot_CSV.csv

Robocopy C:\Autopilot_Export \\Zapp\pc\Hash_Exports /copyall
```

This outputs a CSV file named "Autopilot_CSV.csv" to the `C:\Autopilot_Export` directory and then Robocopy copies it to the Network Share drive inside of the Hash_Exports folder listed above. In the above code, if I manually type in "test", "123", "ABC", etc. and replace "Autopilot_CSV" it will output a CSV under all of those names as well. So it looks like [Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo/3.5) will create a CSV file and save the file name with whatever string you pass into it. Great.

However, I am running this script on multiple different computers and I would like the exported CSV to be named something unique to the machine it is running on so I can easily identify it once it's copied. I am trying to pass the value of the environmental variable `$env:computername` as a string input for the CSV and it isn't working.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
new-item "c:\Autopilot_Export" -type directory -force

Set-Location "C:\Autopilot_Export"

Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile $env:computername.csv

Robocopy C:\Autopilot_Export C:\Users\danieln\Desktop /copyall
```

This code does not generate the CSV file at all. Why not?

Do I just have a basic misunderstanding of how environmental variables are used in Powershell? `$env:computername` appears to return a string of the computer's name, but I cannot pass it into Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo and have it save, but it *will* work if I manually type a string in as the input.

I have also tried setting it to a variable `$computername = [string]$env:computername` and just passing `$computername` in before the .CSV and that doesn't appear to work either. And per the docmentation, environmental variables are apparently already strings.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doublequoting seems to work.  The colon is special in powershell parameters.

```
echo hi | set-content "$env:computername.csv"

dir


    Directory: C:\users\me\foo


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2/11/2021   1:02 PM              4 COMP001.csv
```

The colon is special. For example in switch parameters:

```
get-childitem -force:$true
```

Actually, it's trying to find a property named csv:

```
echo hi | Set-Content  $env:COMPUTERNAME.length
dir


    Directory: C:\Users\me\foo


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2/11/2021   3:04 PM              4 8
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Maybe I just don't completely understand environmental variables and how colons work in Powershell. I would have thought since the value of `$env:comptername` is already a string, it would have worked as such.

Comment: Double-quoting is indeed the right solution, but the need for that is unrelated to the use of `:` (colon). The reason double-quoting is needed here is that `$env:computername.csv` is otherwise interpreted as trying to _access a property named `csv`_ on the object stored in variable `$env:computername`.

Comment: @mklement0 True.

Answer (score 2):

[js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66160252/45375) shows the effective solution: use `"..."`-quoting, i.e. an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) *explicitly*.

**It is a good habit to form to use `"..."` *explicitly* around *command arguments* that are strings *containing* variable references (e.g. `"$HOME/projects"`) or subexpressions (e.g., `"./folder/$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM)"`)**

While such **compound string arguments *generally* do not *require* double-quoting<sup>[1]</sup> - because they are *implicitly* treated as if they were `"..."`-enclosed - in certain cases they *do***, and *when* they do is not obvious and therefore hard to remember:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) details the surprisingly complex rules, but here are **two notable pitfalls if you do *not* use `"..."`**:

- If a compound argument *starts with* a subexpression (`$(...)`), its output is passed *as a separate argument*; e.g. `Write-Output $(Get-Location)/folder` passes *two* arguments to `Write-Output`: the result of `$(Get-Location)` and literal `/folder`
- If a compound argument *starts with* a variable reference *and* is followed by what *syntactically looks like* either (a) a *property access* (e.g., `$PSVersionTable.PsVersion`) or (b) a *method call* (e.g., `$PSHome.Tolower()`) it is *executed as just that, i.e. as an *expression** (rather than being considered a variable reference followed by a literal part).

  - Aside #1: Such an argument then isn't necessarily a *string*, but whatever data type the property value or method-call return value happens to be.
  - Aside #2: A compound string that *starts with* a *quoted string* (whether single- or double-quoted) does *not* work, because the quoted string at the start is also considered an *expression*, like property access and method calls, so that what comes after is again passed as separate argument(s). Therefore, you can only have a compound strings consisting of a mix of quoted and unquoted substrings if the compound string starts with an *unquoted* substring or a non-expression variable reference.<sup>[2]</sup>

The latter is **what happened in this case**:

- ***Unquoted* `$env:computername.csv` was interpreted as an attempt to access *a property named `csv`* on the object stored in (environment) variable `$env:computername`**, and since the `[string]` instance stored there has no `csv` property, the expression evaluated to `$null`.
- By *forcing* PowerShell to interpret this value as an expandable string via `"..."`, the usual [interpolation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) apply, which means that the `.csv` is indeed treated as a *literal* (because property access requires use of `$(...)` in expandable strings).

---

<sup>[1] Quoting *is* required for strings that contain *metacharacters* such as spaces.

For values to be treated *verbatim*, `'...'` quoting is the better choice (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell string literals).

Also, using neither double- nor single-quoting and *individually* `` ` ``-escaping metacharacters is another option (e.g. `` Write-Output C:\Program` Files ``.</sup>

<sup>[2] For instance, `` Write-Output a"b`t"'`c' `` and `` Write-Output $HOME"b`t"'`c' `` work as intended, whereas `` Write-Output "b`t"'`c' `` and `` Write-Output $HOME.Length"b`t"'`c' `` do not (the latter two each pass *3* arguments). The workaround is to either use a *single* `"..."` string with internal `` ` ``-escaping as necessary (e.g. ``` Write-Output "${HOME}b`t``c" ```) or to use string-concatenation expression with `+` enclosed in `(...)` (e.g. `` Write-Output ($HOME + "b`t" + '`c') ``)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Basically pass it a string rather than the variable:

```
write-host $env:computername.csv
# output: (no output - looking for a variable called "computername.csv" instead of "computername")
```

Try the following syntax:

```
$filename = "$($env:computername).csv"
write-host $filename 

# output: MYPCNAME.csv
```

Comment: `"$env:computername.csv"` is enough (or `"${env:computername}.csv"` for conceptual clarity). _looking for a variable called "computername.csv"_ is incorrect - `$env:computername.csv`, when used in isolation _unquoted_, tries to access a property named `.csv` on the value of `$env:computername`

Comment: As an aside: I suggest not using `Write-Host` in sample code, as it might mislead beginners to think that (a) using a cmdlet is necessary to produce output in PowerShell (it isn't) and that (b) the cmdlet to use for producing output is `Write-Host` (it generally isn't, unless your intent is to _write directly to the screen_ (host) rather than to _output data_).