# Powershell: How to remove space between $ and text[0]

Tags: powershell

Code:

```
$text=Get-Content -Path "E:\1.txt"
$text.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize
For($i=0; $i -le 5 ;$i++)
{
    $var=Write-host '$'text[$i] 
    $var
}
```

Actual Result:

```
$ text[0]
$ text[1]
$ text[2]
$ text[3]
$ text[4]
$ text[5]
```

I need below Result:

```
$text[0]
$text[1]
$text[2]
$text[3]
$text[4]
$text[5]
```

Comment: It's pretty straight forward: `\`$text[$i]`

Comment: if it is powershell only, why did you tag c#?

Comment: As @Clijsters says. Simply do ``Write-Host "`$text[$i]"``

Comment: Are you looking to display literally just `$text[$i]`?  Or the the value of it? You can always single quote to display the literal variable,  you can also escape the variable depending on what you want to do. You can also use a sub-expression `$()` to do something as well such as displaying the value in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code fundamentally doesn't do what you intend it to do, due to the mistaken use of [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)**:

```
# !! Doesn't capture anything in $var, prints directly to the screen.
$var=Write-host '$'text[$i] 
$var # !! is effectively $null and produces no output.
```

See the bottom section for details.

---

Instead, **what you want is an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)** (aka interpolating string, `"..."`-enclosed), with selective `` ` ``-escaping of the `$` character you want to be treated *verbatim*:

```
$var= "`$text[$i]" # Expandable string; ` escapes the $ char., $i is expanded
$var
```

There are **other ways to construct the desired string**:

- `$var = '$text[{0}]' -f $i`, using `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f).
- `$var = '$' + "text[$i]"`, using *string concatenation* with `+`

but the above approach is simplest in your case.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- **`Write-Host` is typically - and definitely in your case - [the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only***, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).
- **What you thought of as a *single* argument, `'$'text[$i]`, was actually passed as *two* arguments**, verbatim `$` and *expanded* `text[$i]` (e.g., `text[0]`) and because `Write-Host` simply *space-concatenates* multiple arguments, a space was effectively inserted in the (for-display) output.
- **That `'$'text[$i]` becomes *two* arguments is a perhaps surprising PowerShell idiosyncrasy**; unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, **composing a single string argument from a mix of unquoted and (potentially differently) quoted parts only works if the argument starts with an *unquoted* substring or *(mere) variable reference***; for instance:

  - `Write-Output foo'bar none'` *does* pass a single argument (passes `foobar none`), whereas
  - `Write-Output 'bar none'foo` does *not* (passes `bar none` and `foo`)
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161666/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use the quotes, using `-separator` also works:

```
$text=Get-Content -Path "E:\1.txt"
$text.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize

For($i=0; $i -le 5 ;$i++)
{
    $var=Write-host '$'text[$i] -Separator ''
    $var
}
```

Comment: While that is an interesting workaround, note that the fundamental problem is that `Write-Host` does't write to PowerShell's success output stream and prints directly to the host (in PSv5+, strictly speaking, via the _information_ output stream, number `6`). Therefore, nothing is captured in variable `$var`.