# Docker run: invalid reference format error unbricking switch

Tags: docker, powershell

trying to finish my switch "saves" from bricking.

error on last command on powershell:

1. COMMAND: docker pull pablozaiden/deviceid-exosphere-builder
   NO PROBLEM
2. COMMAND: mkdir -p ./output
   FINE
3. COMMAND docker run -ti --rm -e DEVICEID=0x0065994B921FFA0A -v "$PWD"/output:/output pablozaiden/deviceid-exosphere-builder:latest

ERROR: Docker: invalid reference format

What is could be?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Either: ***remove* the `"` around `$PWD`** (this will also work fine in directories whose paths happen to contain spaces):

```sh
docker run -ti --rm -e DEVICEID=0x0065994B921FFA0A -v $PWD/output:/output pablozaiden/deviceid-exosphere-builder:latest
```

Or: **enclose the *entire* argument in `"..."`**:

```sh
docker run -ti --rm -e DEVICEID=0x0065994B921FFA0A -v "$PWD/output:/output" pablozaiden/deviceid-exosphere-builder:latest
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`"$PWD"/output:/output` is passed as *two* arguments by PowerShell:

- the (stringified) value of the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) representing the current location (directory)
- verbatim `/output:/output`

Unlike POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, **PowerShell doesn't support composing a single string argument from a mix of quoted and unquoted tokens, *except* if the *initial* token is *unquoted***.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161666/45375) for details.