# How can I concatenate a variable and string without spaces in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm importing some values from a csv file and using them to create a adb command for an Android intent with the following code.

```
Write-Host adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW '-d' '"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' $($c.number)'"'
```

This gives me an out put of:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone= 12345678 "
```

How can I remove the spaces where the variable is concatenated to the string to give the output of:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=12345678"
```

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g, `$value`, instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375). To explicitly print only to the display _but with rich formatting_, use `Out-Host`.

Comment: Specifically, using `Write-Host` here obscures the distinction between actual spaces in the arguments and multiple arguments being separated with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *[string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2)* by switching to double quotes:

```sh
Write-Host adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW '-d' "`"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$($c.number)`""
```

Within double quotes, you have to backtick-escape double quotes to output them literally.

Answer (score 2):

[zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74198124/45375) is unquestionably the best solution to your problem.

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
Write-Host ... '"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' $($c.number)'"'
```

- The fact that there is a *space* before `$($c.number)` implies that you're passing at least *two* arguments.
- However, due to PowerShell's argument-mode parsing quirks, you're passing *three*, because the `'"'` string that directly follows `$($c.number)` too becomes its own argument.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161666/45375) for more information.

Therefore, ***compound* string arguments (composed of a mix of quoted and unquoted / differently quoted tokens) are best avoided in PowerShell.**

Therefore:

- Either: Use a *single*, [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), as in zett42's answer.
- Or: Use an *expression* enclosed in `(...)` and use *string concatenation* with the [`+`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators) operator, as shown below.

```
Write-Host ... ('"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + $c.number + '"')
```