# Extra Space needs to remove while executing powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am executing the below script on the windows server as a PowerShell script -

```
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm')
echo "Date & Time : $today"

powershell -Command "Copy-Item -Recurse 'C:\ABC' -Destination 'C:\ABC_"$today"'"
```

The above script is working fine but there is a blank space between ABC & Date while creating the directory. Please please help me on this how can I remove this blank space.

```
**Directory Name :** ModelFactoryProducti**on_ 28**_06_2021_11_05
**Directory Name Should be :** ModelFactoryProduction_28_06_2021_11_05
```

Comment: You tagged this question as powershell 2 **and** 3. It probably doesn't matter here, but if you specify a version, then please specify only the version you are using.

Comment: to remove that unwanted space, remove the unneeded quotes around the `$Today` variable AND replace the single, outer quotes with double quotes.. ///// also, you REALLY otta use a sortable date format. the silly day/month/year thing is ... silly. instead, use year/month/day to get a sane, sensible, SORTABLE string value. [*grin*]

Comment: Good point about needing to remove the `"` around `$today`, @Lee_Dailey, but that is all that is needed, given that the immediately enclosing `'...'` string is itself embedded in a larger, expandable `"..."` string.

Comment: @mklement0 - yep ... but the nested quotes is where the space is coming from. i have no idea WHY ... but a simple test shows that unwanted space. my suggestion to the OP is to build the whole string ahead of time.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, my answer explains where the space is coming from.

Comment: @mklement0 - oooo! thank you for pointing that out to me ... i was wondering about it ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling *from PowerShell*, the best option is to pass a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) to `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe).

- However, this raises the question: why do you need to call the CLI *from* PowerShell to begin with, given that you could just call your `Copy-Item` command *directly*, without the overhead (and potential loss of type fidelity) that comes with creating *another* PowerShell session, via a *child process*.

if you still need to call the PowerShell CLI from PowerShell itself, use the following:

```sh
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm')

powershell -Command { 
  Copy-Item -Recurse 'C:\ABC' -Destination ('C:\ABC_' + $args[0]) 
} -args $today
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

Removing the `"` around `$today` in `'C:\ABC_"$today"'` would have worked too - the *outer* `"..."` quoting would still have ensured that `$today` is expanded.

- **What you thought of as a *single* string argument,
  `"Copy-Item -Recurse 'C:\ABC' -Destination 'C:\ABC_"$today"'"`, was passed as *two* arguments**:

  - Argument 1: Verbatim `Copy-Item -Recurse 'C:\ABC' -Destination 'C:\ABC_`, which, due to being a (double-)*quoted* token became its *own* argument - despite other characters immediately following it.
  - Argument 2: The value of `$today`, immediately followed by a verbatim `'` (the value of `"'"`), e.g., verbatim `06_2021_11_05'`
  - *Not* being able to compose a single argument from a mix of quoted and unquoted tokens *if the first token happens to be quoted* is a notable pitfall, discussed in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66144160/45375).
- When you use `-Command` and pass *multiple* arguments, PowerShell simply joins those arguments to form a single string by placing *a space* between them, before interpreting the resulting string as PowerShell code.

  - Therefore, your *two* verbatim arguments, `Copy-Item -Recurse 'C:\ABC' -Destination 'C:\ABC_` and (e.g.) `06_2021_11_05'` were ultimately interpreted as
    `Copy-Item -Recurse 'C:\ABC' -Destination 'C:\ABC_ 06_2021_11_05'` - note the unwanted space.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136129/45375) for a comprehensive overview of the PowerShell CLI (covers both `powershell.exe` and `pwsh`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$today = (Get-Date -format 'dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm')
Copy-Item -Recurse 'C:\ABC' -Destination "C:\ABC_$today"
```

When possible, avoid using either of these kinds of syntax, as it's very simple to allow accidentally (or maliciously) inserting extra data into the command string. Plus, you're already in powershell - no need to execute `powershell` again unless you left it to run some cmd commands:

```
powershell -c "Write-Host $var"
Invoke-Expression -Command 'Write-Host "$var"'
```