# How to pass environment variables for a new container in Azure via PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to execute the next command:

```
az container create --resource-group myresourcegroup --name mycontainer --image myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:latest --dns-name-label mysite --ports 80 --environment-variables 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'='postgresql://psql.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres?user=myuser@psql&password=myPassword&sslmode=require'
```

I used [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_create)

But it fails due to **PowerShell** doesn't recognize the string after `'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'=` as string. It parses the last one as command arguments. I tried to pass environment variables as a dict `@{'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'='myconnectionstring'}` but it didn't help.

**What's a right way to make it?**

Answer (score 1):

**In PowerShell, do *not* try to compose a single string from multiple, possibly *quoted*, strings by *direct adjoining* - perhaps surprisingly, that won't work if the *first* string *happens to be quoted***, because it then *becomes its own argument* - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66144160/45375) for more information.

Instead, use:

- either: a *single* quoted string (e.g., `'foo bar'` or `"foo $(Get-Date)"`)
- or: an *expression* with `+` that synthesizes a string from verbatim and expandable (interpolating) strings, as needed (e.g., `('The value of $HOME is: ' + "$HOME.")`

---

In your case, a single verbatim (`'...'`) string<sup>[1]</sup> will do.

That is, instead of what you tried (which is passed as *two* arguments):

```sh
'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'='postgresql://psql.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres?user=myuser@psql&password=myPassword&sslmode=require'
```

pass (note that only *overall* `'...'` quoting is used):

```sh
'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=postgresql://psql.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres?user=myuser@psql&password=myPassword&sslmode=require'
```

---

<sup>[1] See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of string literals in PowerShell.</sup>